# Scrollable div trouble in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a div which visibility is being switched. The div also has the scrollable propertie overflow. The code works correct in Firefox. But in Chrome the scroolbar is seen even if the div visibility is set to hidden. How to fix this?

CSS:

```
.dhHelp{
position:absolute;
top:5px;
left:6px;
visibility: hidden;
width: 120px;
height: 220px;
z-index:999;
background-color:black;
border: solid #33ccff 2px;
font-size: 10px;
overflow:scroll;
color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually in `visibility : hidden` - element will take its space , so scroll bar is there, 
try after `display:none` - with this property it will not take space in your page and will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The overflow:scroll statement forces to show the scrollbar in any browser. Maybe try display:none, to don't display the div, if you want it so.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue for this in chrome.
If you want it to disappear, use height, width:0.